# iOS 7 iFrame Scroll Disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have seen many posts about iOS traditionally not supporting scrolling `iFrames`, like most desktop browsers, however most of the posts are quite old. They reference iOS 4 and iOS 6.

With iOS 7 and iOS 8, is there any way to embed an `iFrame` (lets say as an example, a PDF, into a web-page that would be loaded by the native `webkit`, rendering engine)?

Here are the techniques which I have tried, but have not worked:

1. Adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` into the `iFrame`
2. Setting the `iFrame`'s overflow to `auto` or `scroll`
3. Embedding the `iFrame` within a `div` (the problems here are that the div scrolls to the height of the `iFrame`, but the `iFrame` height has to be exactly the height of the document for this to work perfectly)

Sample HTML:

```
<iframe src="file.pdf"></iframe>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183647/scrolling-iframe-on-ios-is-solved-but-the-iframe-page-display-incomplete

Comment: @Khaleel thanks for posting a possible solution. Unfortunately, the scrolling with "nice scroll" is not very smooth. Are there any other projects that may be smoother scrolling?